# Is there an elegant way to generate the surfaces of an N-dimensional prism from only min and max points?

Tags: python, arrays, spatial, surface

Say I have an N-dimensional prism, bounded by two points: the minimum, and the maximum. In three dimensions, this would be the lower-left and upper-right points on the prism.

The bounds of a prism is technically all one needs to define the prism, and yet I am having difficulty extrapolating certain pieces of information.

I can get a list of all the points using a cartesian product.

But is there an elegant way to calculate a list of surfaces from this starting point?

For example, a three dimensional cube bounded by (0, 0, 0) and (1, 1, 1) would have these surfaces:

```
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 0, 1)]
[(0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1)]
[(0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 0)]
[(1, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0)]
[(1, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 0), (1, 1, 0)]
[(1, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1), (0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1)]
```

It bears mentioning that I ultimately intend to display these surfaces graphically. Hence, part of the issue I am dealing with is that the points for each surface should be in an order that actually defines a closed surface. So, the surface:

```
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 0, 1)]
```

is valid, but

```
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1)]
```

is not in the right order, since the edges cross over each other (and I cannot think of a very good approach to putting the points in their proper order).

I have tried and failed to think of a way to calculate the list of surfaces for a prism that isn't horribly messy. Any advice on the correct way to tackle this would be much appreciated.

I realize this is an oddly specific question. However, I believe there *should* be a good approach to solve this, and I can't seem to find it. How does one go about solving a problem like this?

Comment: Are you planning to visualise higher dimensions than 3D? Sides of 4D hypercubes are actually regular 3d cubes (8 of them). You cannot really visualise a 3d cube with a single linestrip of 8 vertices.

Answer (score 0):

In the N-dimensional hypercube (think that is the real name of what you are generating), a valid edge is where only one of the coordinates are changing. That is why (0,1,0)-(0,0,1) does not work, while (0,1,0)-(0,1,1) does.

That part is sure. <strike>However defining a hypersurface for the hypercube is just a gut feeling: I think it involves having one coordinate fixed, and the other N-1 going "around".</strike> It is more complicated, see Wikipedia: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube#Elements